# If $G$ is finite abelian and there exists an element of order $> 2$ then $|Aut(G)|$ is even

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

I would appreciate if you could please evaluate my proof and point out any mistakes I made.

Proof:

Since $G$ is abelian, $Inn(G) \cong \{1\}$, thus $Aut(G) = Out(G)$. But the only automorphisms possible are permutations of the elements of $G$. In addition, every automorphism must preserve the identity. Suppose $|G|=n > 2$. Therefore, $|Aut(G)|=\frac{(n-1)!}{2!}$, where $(n-1)!$ is even since all factorials $>1$ are even.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Most permutations of the elements of $G$ will fail to be automorphisms.

Comment: Not every permutation which fixes the identity is an automorphism.  For instance, any automorphism has to preserve the order of an element (while permutation do not).  Hint:  consider the map $g:\to g^{-1}$.  Is it an automorphism?  Can it be trivial?  What is its order?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But what if there exist other automorphisms besides the $g: \to g^{-1}$?

Comment: Also, what if there exists one element of order $3$ and one element of order $4$ in $G$? The rest of the elements are of orders $1$ and $2$. Then there will be one identity outer automorphism, one automorphism for the element of order $3$ and one - for order $4$. That would be three automorphisms, which is not even. Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your attempt to a proof is completely wrong. You can't just count permutations of $G$ that fix $1$, because they aren't generally automorphisms. Only *some* permutations fixing $1$ are.

---

The map $\iota\colon G\to G$ defined by $\iota(x)=x^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$ if and only if $G$ is abelian.

Clearly $\iota\circ\iota=\mathit{id}_G$ is the identity.

Let $x\in G$ have order $n>2$. Then $\iota(x)=x^{n-1}\ne x$ and so $\iota\ne\mathit{id}_G$.

Therefore $\iota$ has order $2$. So $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ has a subgroup of order $2$.

Note that the finiteness of $G$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

let $i(g)=g^{-1}, F:Aut(G)\rightarrow Aut(G)$ defined by $F(f)=i\circ f$, $F^2$ is the identity. Suppose $F(f)=f$, let $x\in G, x^n=1, n>2$ and $f(u)=x, F(f)(u)=i(f(u))=i(x)=x^{n-1}\neq x$ contradiction. So $F$ is an involution of $Aut(G)$ without fixed point, thus the cardinal of $Aut(G)$ is even.